# iOS web view renderer doesn't update its value

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have implemented WebViewRenderer it works well on Android but it doesn't work on iOS. It displays the value, but then user clicks next button and the value doesn't update. I have tried the the example on ms website, but that displayed no text, I don't have the values from URL. I have also tried several post here.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ExtendedWebView), typeof(ExtendedWebViewRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class ExtendedWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<ExtendedWebView, WKWebView>
    {      
        WKWebView _wkWebView;
        static ExtendedWebView _xwebView = null;

        protected  override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ExtendedWebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                WKWebViewConfiguration config = new WKWebViewConfiguration();

                _wkWebView = new WKWebView(Frame, config);
                _wkWebView.NavigationDelegate = new CustomWKNavigationDelegate(this);

                SetNativeControl(_wkWebView);
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                HtmlWebViewSource source = (Xamarin.Forms.HtmlWebViewSource)Element.Source;

                string html = source.Html;
                _wkWebView.LoadHtmlString(html, baseUrl: null);
                _wkWebView.ScrollView.ScrollEnabled = false;
                _wkWebView.SizeToFit();
            }
        }
    }
        
    public class CustomWKNavigationDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate
    {

        ExtendedWebViewRenderer _webViewRenderer;

        public CustomWKNavigationDelegate(ExtendedWebViewRenderer webViewRenderer)
        {
            _webViewRenderer = webViewRenderer;
        }

        public  override async void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
        {
            var wv = _webViewRenderer.Element as ExtendedWebView;
            if (wv != null)
            {
                await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(100); // wait here till content is rendered
                wv.HeightRequest = (double)webView.ScrollView.ContentSize.Height;
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ExtendedWebView), typeof(ExtendedWebViewRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class ExtendedWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    { 
        public static int _webViewHeight;
        static ExtendedWebView _xwebView = null;
        public WebView _webView;
        bool isScroll;

        [Obsolete]
        public ExtendedWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
          
        }
     
        class ExtendedWebViewClient : WebViewClient
        {
            WebView _webView;
 
            public async override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
            {
                try
                {
                    _webView = view;
                    if (_xwebView != null)
                    {

                        view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                        await Task.Delay(100);
                        string result = await _xwebView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("(function(){return document.body.scrollHeight;})()");
                        _xwebView.HeightRequest = Convert.ToDouble(result);
                    }
                    base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{ex.Message}");
                }
            }
            public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(Android.Webkit.WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            _xwebView = e.NewElement as ExtendedWebView;
            _webView = Control;

            if (e.OldElement == null)
            {
                _webView.SetWebViewClient(new ExtendedWebViewClient());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class ExtendedWebView : WebView
{
    public ExtendedWebView()
    {
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<controls:ExtendedWebView 
VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.RowSpan="2"
x:Name="enView"
Opacity="1"
Source="{Binding CZ, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

```
private static HtmlWebViewSource htmlSourceExplanation = new HtmlWebViewSource();

public HtmlWebViewSource Cz
{
    get { return _cz; }
    set
    {
        _cz = value;

        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Cz));
    }
}
```

```
private void SetExplanationDetail(string text, string text2)
{
    htmlSourceExplanation.Html = _style + "<div class=\"text\"><div>" + text + "</div><div>" + text2 + "</div></div>";
    _cz = htmlSourceExplanation;
    NotifyPropertyChanged("Cz");

}
```

I expect the value to change once to user cliks the button. `

Comment: I try to reproduce the problem but the code above is not full. In addition, what does the `its value` mean?

Comment: I am sorry there should be in xaml CZ, its a text value

Comment: the value comes from SetExplanationDetail @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: I still can't create the sample with your code. What is the `_style` and where was the `SetExplanationDetail` method called? Can you provide a small sample whihc can reproduce the problem on the github?

Comment: yes, will do. @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: https://github.com/Novotnde/WebView2 @LiyunZhang-MSFT sorry it took so long

Comment: I have test your project and the the two strings both show in the webview on the android and ios. And there is no value needed updated. What is your probelm?